# Why can't TypeScript Objects index with generic types?

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

In JavaScript, plain old objects can take all kinds of abuse. For example you can write:

```js
var obj = {};
var func = new Function() {};
obj[func] = 5; // totally fine
obj[func]; // returns 5
```

With some creativity you could write a generic class `SimpleSet<T>` that might use an object as its backing store in JavaScript or TypeScript. One straightforward way may involve writing something like this:

```typescript
public add(val: T) {
  this._dict[val] = val;
}
```

Which doesn't work in TypeScript. **Why?** More permissive versions of `add` work, see `add2` and `add3`.

```typescript
class SimpleSet<T> {
  _dict: Object;
  constructor() {

  }

  // error:
  public add(val: T) {
    this._dict[val] = val;
  }

  // no error:    
  public add2(val: T) {
    this._dict[val as any] = val;
  }

  // no error:
  public add3(val: any) {
    this._dict[val] = val;
  }
}
```

With `add`, two errors appear:

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Object[T]'.
>
> Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Object'.

[image]

### **Why?**

Comment: Your function creation syntax is wrong, but do you realize setting a function as the key to a JS object will cast the function to a string, creating a key something like this: `"function (){}"`?

Comment: `var obj = {}; var key1 = {prop1:'val1'}; var key2 = {prop2:'val2'}; obj[key1] = "hello"; console.log(Object.keys(obj));` will log `["[object Object]"]`. Logging `obj[key2]` will show "hello" because the `toString()` of both objects are the same.

Comment: You've gotten pretty far on something that doesn't work...

Comment: I wasn't trying to make a workable set here (this would be insane in JS too), but trying to figure out the rule for `any` being allowed vs `Object` being disallowed as a type. I see now I was under the mistaken belief that `any` means "allow all types", instead of "opt out of type checking."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't let you because it doesn't work, which is a pretty decent reason as far as things go.

The indexing keys of JavaScript objects are *always* (**always**) `string`s. Indexing by other sorts of things coerces the key to a string and then looks up by that. For example, as pointed out in comments, indexing by an object produces the key `"[object Object]"`

You can use the ES6 `Map` object for a working object-to-value store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still fooling around with TS, trying to figure out what's allowed and what's not. Obviously this set implementation would be silly in JS too. I thought it was interesting that `any` is allowed as an index type, yet `Object` is not. I see now I was under the mistaken belief that `any` meant "allow all types", instead of "opt out of type checking."